# MySQL - Cascade update works but cascade delete doesn't

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

There are two tables; proizvodi (parent) table, and normativ (child table), relation 1:N.

Primary key on parent table is field Sifra, and on child table SifraProizvoda.
When I make an update in parent table, the change reflects on child table but if I try to delete something in parent table i get error:

> /* SQL Error (1451): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`racuni`.`cijenapro`, CONSTRAINT `FK_cijenapro_proizvodi` FOREIGN KEY (`SifraProizvoda`) REFERENCES `proizvodi` (`Sifra`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) */

Here is the structure of tables [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b3ed)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it seems that ON DELETE NO ACTION isn't same as ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: i don't understand this because i had defined on delete cascade on update cascade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `ON DELETE CASCADE` too along with the `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. What you have now is `ON DELETE NO ACTION` so the foreign key association is stopping you from deleting the parent as it doesn't want orphaned children. If you had the `ON DELETE CASCADE` as well, the parent and child entries will both be deleted. You can use a `ALTER TABLE` to add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the table. You have to drop the existing constraint first as only one constraint is allowed for both `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: Does it mean that I can have both actions defined? I had tried with creating two FK-s, one for update and second one for delete but doesn't help.

Comment: I just updated my answer. You have to drop the existing constraint and recreate it. Something like this.

alter table AllowedCars 
  drop constraint FK_AllowedCars_CarID 

alter table table 
  add constraint FK_AllowedCars_CarID 
      foreign key (CarID) 
      references Cars(CarID) 
      on delete cascade 
      on update cascade

Comment: Already do that. Doesn't work. The strange thing is that update is working but deleting record don't.

Comment: Did you drop constraint `FK_cijenapro_proizvodi` and re-add it with both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE? It still doesn't work?

Comment: Now it works. Don't know how but after deleteing and recreating few times sunddenly works. Thanks for help end effort.

Comment: Awesome. Please upvote/accept my answer if it helped you.